# Which side of double sink do I connect garbage disposal? NEWBIE

Tags: plumbing, garbage-disposal

I have a double sink in kitchen same size. Looking to install garbage disposal for my first time. Do I install it on the right (white pipe) or left side (black pipe)?

I assume the right side (white piping) since my dishwasher is connected to it and drainage is on the left side.

Is this correct?

Thank you

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsYJ9.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsYJ9.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeEVs.jpg)[image][image]

Comment: Why install a disposer? Do you have waste pickup for food garbage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably find the right side easier to plumb as there is just more space.  Disposals have sort of a weird offset discharge pipe that isn't just a drop in replacement for the existing extension pipe.  As you noted the dishwasher piping already runs to the right as well, and that is generally connected to the disposal.